Color filter to invert widget color?
I have a wordpress site.
There is a white/light widget in the middle, but it has no support for a dark theme.
I want to make it dark somehow.
Is there any possibility to change the widget color?
I tried a tablble with the widget inside - but I can't find a way to invert the color of the table content...
The Widget-Code:


<iframe src="//www.fxblue.com/fxbluechart.aspx?c=ch_cumulativeprofit&amp;id=refactorscalper01" frameborder="0" width="400" height="200"><a href="//www.fxblue.com">FX Blue - free tools and services for FX and CFD traders</a></iframe>



there is is no way to change the widget color itself.
